# the map view didn't show in my program?

Tags: android, google-maps

I follow the procedure of hellogooglemap example and it was working nicely but i don't know now with my galaxy s9000 didn't show the map only. i didn't know why it happened. is there any updating for

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

in manifest file or what?

Comment: give us more info as to what you mean by it was working (on which device) and what are you seeing? Is your phone connected to internet?

Comment: when i test the program ( showing the googlemap) in AVD and it wark normally but when i install in the phone showing grid. i don't know why?

Comment: I test the program of googlemap in AVD and it work normally but when i install it in my galaxy s9000 framework 2.2, it is showing grid instead of map.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct google maps API key defined. The key should correspond to the certificate you have used to sign the application. As a check make sure that internet connectivity to the phone is good as without internet the map wont load.